# CKEditor styles menu doesn't load <a> styles

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have the following set in the CKEditor config:

```
config.stylesSet = "[{ name : 'Button', element : 'a', attributes : { 'class' : 'button' } }]";
```

If the editor starts empty, when creating a link, the Styles dropdown doesn't show / allow us to apply the 'button' style.

If the editor loads with links in it, the Styles menu does show the 'Button' style fine.

Is there a way to force the editor to reload the styles menu after the link has been added?

Comment: can you please make jsfiddle demo. thanks

Comment: it would take quite a lot of setup. is there any reason it would not load the <a> styles with an empty editor?

Comment: I think you have to use `allowedContent` and specify `<a>` tag. view this http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-string-format

Comment: aren't these set by default. would have thought an <a> would be supported? to confirm, it works fine if there's html already in there and an <a> is present. it just doesn't work if you start with an empty editor. it's like the stylesset isn't loaded.